# Ubuntu 13.04 - can't login to Unity, keep going back to login screen with all users

Tags: 13.04, lightdm, login-screen, gdm

today I've updated openssl and libssl (automatic update). After reboot I can't login with any user (even with Guest or new one) into X.
I've tried with installing gdm, gnome-session-fallback - no luck.

On login screen (no matter if it's lightdm or gdm) I type password, it tries to login, then screen goes black and returns to login screen.

I've found somewhere solution with Xauthority and xsession-errors, but in .xsession-errors I don't have anything but two lines:

Script for cjkv started at run_im.
  Script for default starter at run_im.

I'm using Linux for about 10 years, but I can't find anything in /var/log that can point me to solution. Reinstalling Ubuntu IS NOT A SOLUTION for me.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04.
Guest user could login, but not me.

I'd deleted `.Xauthority` for my user and reboot. It gives some problems alerts during the boot but it worked fine.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login in shell, and then `rm /home/<user>/.Xauthority`.
Then `sudo reboot`.

Thanks davmp

Comment: I didn't even had to reboot

Comment: Worked for Unity on 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Solution from OP:

---

I've found the solution. Somehow automatic updates installed libssl1 for amd64 AND i386.

I've noticed this after I've tried to ssh to another pc - ssh just quits without any message. I've reinstalled the amd64 version of libssl and now everything works.

Comment: same thing happens with me with 13.04 but i have to re-install it because i am very new to ubuntu. can you please explain how you resolve it in step by step. because i don't how to use ubuntu after you came on black command screen (alt+f2). may be it is helpful for others and me (next time). thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same symptoms on my 13.04 machine.  I was able to log in remotely and run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This resolved the problem for me - did not even have to reset.

Comment: not need to do remotely - I switch over desktop to terminal with ALT+CTRL+F1 and there I could login and did the update

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was simply a bad .Xauthority and/or .xsession files.  You can test for this by seeing if another user on the machine can log in successfully.  If so, the problem is something about *you*.

The solution is to delete those files out of my home directory.  After this, a Unity login worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

After an extremely long time searching for the answer... This is what worked for me:
     Ctrl+Alt+F1 then I entered
     sudo install gnome and after the install I entered
     sudo reboot

I logged in using the gnome environment although I have heard of someone logging back in with the ubuntu environment also!

ps: this was with the 14.04 version