# Back to the login screen immediately after login

Tags: 14.04, gnome, 15.04, login, lightdm

After login the the default gnome desktop, there is nothing but only a background picture. Then after a flash of a black screen, it returns back to the login interface.

I changed to tty1 by `Ctrl+Alt+F1`. By typing `startx` I can log into gnome with icons on the desktop but without gnome panel. I added `mutter` and `gnome-panel` into the **Startup Applications** so that I don't have to run them in the terminal every time. Then I can use this gnome environment as usual.

But change back to the default desktop by `Ctrl+Alt+F7`, I still cannot login.

To sum up, I cannot login the default gnome, but can login the gnome started by `startx`.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://askubuntu.com/questions/316778/ubuntu-13-04-cant-login-to-unity-keep-going-back-to-login-screen-with-all-us

Comment: @tanay i tried before. Deleting .Xauthority and .xerrors* doesn't give any help.

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Comment: @GarrettR No. I think I'll make a reinstall of Ubuntu some other day.

Comment: After the newly update, it can login now. But there is still problem with the desktop. The windows are boardless and can not be resized by dragging.